# Bootstrap v3.3.5 popover placement

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a hard time using the new bootstrap popovers. I think it might be a bug, but I'm not completely sure.

Here is my example.
http://jsbin.com/vohariwuja/edit?html,js,output

Basically I'm trying to use popovers to display error messages in a form. When I try to add a popover to an element **that is not on the screen**, the popover doesn't align properly. The strange thing about it is, it only happens when i use **right** or **left** placement. If I set the placement of the popover to top, bottom, or auto then it works just fine (this is noted in the example).

**Goal**
This example shows what I'm trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/1ejmvg1v/
It is using version 3.1.1. Scroll down, click 'Test' button, scroll up, and the popover is correctly placed.

HTML

```
  <div class="form-group col-xs-4 ErrorDiv has-feedback " style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" rel="popover">
    <input class="form-control" name="Input1" id="Input1"  value="" type="text">    
  </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 ErrorDiv has-feedback " style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" rel="popover">
    <input class="form-control" name="Input2" id="Input2"  value="" type="text">    
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
var PopoverOptions = {
  html: true ,
  placement: 'right',
  /* This one works
  placement: 'bottom',
  */
  template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content ErrorContentDiv"></div></div>',
  title: '<button class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>',
  trigger: 'manual',
  content: function()
  {
    var _element = $(this);
    if( (_element.attr('data-error-message') !== undefined) && (_element.attr('data-error-message') !== null)  && ($.trim(_element.attr('data-error-message')).length > 0 ) )
    {
      return _element.attr('data-error-message');
    }
    else
      return "";
  }
};



$.each($('.ErrorDiv'),function(){

  $(this).attr('data-error-message','This is a error message')
    .popover(PopoverOptions)
    .popover('show');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by setting viewport to false so that it overrides the default value and using the container option for the popover. It feels a little hackish in that I would have preferred to not alter the settings for each popover. I.E container = false | string | function support.

If anyone has a better solution I'm all ears.

JavaScript

```
var PopoverOptions = {
  html: true ,
  placement: 'right',
  /* This one works
  placement: 'bottom',
  */
  template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content ErrorContentDiv"></div></div>',
  title: '<button class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>',
  trigger: 'manual',
  content: function()
  {
    var _element = $(this);
    if( (_element.attr('data-error-message') !== undefined) && (_element.attr('data-error-message') !== null)  && ($.trim(_element.attr('data-error-message')).length > 0 ) )
    {
      return _element.attr('data-error-message');
    }
    else
      return "";
  },
  viewport: false
};



$.each($('.ErrorDiv'),function(){

  var _ErrorDiv = $(this);
  var _temp = $.extend({}, PopoverOptions,{container: _ErrorDiv});
  $(this).attr('data-error-message','This is a error message')
    .popover(_temp)
    .popover('show');

});
```